# Text recognition cloud API in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, cloud

I want to add text recognition API in flutter project anyone help, please.
I couldn't find any source code. there are already flutter plugins available but they are not so accurate.

Comment: try [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_ml_vision)

Comment: thank you for your response brother but i have already tried this it is inaccurate i want to this code in flutter: [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-image-objects-android/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6)